# Page-break-after work fine in ff but not working in ie

Tags: css, printing

I am using Page-break-after:always for my div and it works fine in FF but in IE the page-break does not appear
this is my div

```
<div style="page-break-after:always">
...
...
...
...
</div>
```

Comment: Including your code might help...

Comment: IE and Firefox do not support the property values "left" or "right" for the page-break-after class...

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="word-break: break-all;">
 ...
 ...
 ...
 ...
</div>
```